# Creating a document fragment in YUI 2.x

Tags: javascript, yui

Is it possible to create a document fragment from a string and get a reference to it using the YUI 2.x API?  If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

YUI 2 does not have DOM creation utilities.  You'll need to create the doc frag and populate it yourself.